# Embed a SVG file in a tex source file

Tags: graphics, packages, svg, text-manipulation, embedding

I would like to generate latex documents containing SVG pictures with a specific document generator. For specific reasons, I would like to embed these pictures directly inside the latex source file to avoid creating and copying additional files.

**Is it possible to create latex functions containing the XML code of a SVG pictures and make them usable by the [svg package](https://ctan.org/pkg/svg)?**

Comment: just put them in a `filecontents` environment so they are written to file before the svg package needs them

Comment: Is your question resolved? If not, please explain why David's suggestion does not work for you.